# Equation not displayed in latex

Tags: latex

The equation below does not display in latex. Also, the introductory text does not display properly(all words together without space and in italics)

```
A common form of this potential is the 12-6 Lennard Jones (LJ) potential 
expressed as equation 2.7

\begin{align}
    U_{ij}= 4\epsilon_{ij}[(\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij})^12-
                (\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij})^6]
\end{align}
```

Also, in the text below, all words are together without space and in italics.

```
Where \epsilon_{ij} and  \sigma{ij} represent well depth and diameter of 
the atom respectively. \epsilon_{ij} and  \sigma_{ij} for unlike atoms 
are determined using Lorentz-Berthelot combination rules [44] given in 
equations 2.8 and 2.9
```

Your help is appreciated.
I attach here a picture of the output.

[image]

Comment: Please use proper code formatting in your question. Regarding why you get this ugly output, it's probably because your have a math environment that wasn't closed _before_ what you're showing us.

Comment: Thank you. I have now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not using inline math mode properly. In the image you posted

[image]

it shows that your text is preceded by (what looks like) `\epsilon_{ij}`. `\epsilon` *requires* a math font, and therefore you should use `$\epsilon_{ij}$`. The same goes for any inline math you want to typeset. This would be the suggested/proper coding:

```
A common form of this potential is the 12-6 Lennard Jones (LJ) potential 
expressed as equation~\eqref{eq:lj-potential},
\begin{equation}
  U_{ij} = 4 \epsilon_{ij} [ (\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij})^{12} 
            - (\frac{\sigma_{ij}}{r_{ij})^6 ] \label{eq:lj-potential}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon_{ij}$ and $\sigma{ij}$ represent well depth and diameter of 
the atom respectively. $\epsilon_{ij}$ and $\sigma_{ij}$ for unlike atoms 
are determined using Lorentz-Berthelot combination rules~\cite{lorentz-berthelot}
given in equations~\eqref{eq:epsilon} and~\eqref{eq:sigma}.
```

Note the following:

1. Use `equation` for a single-line numbered equation; `align` is for multi-line equations (that may require alignment).
2. No blank line (paragraph break) before `equation`.
3. Use `\label`s and `\ref`s (or `\eqref`, since you're using [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) since equation numbers can change. Let TeX take care of storing and recalling these numbers.
4. Use `\cite` to reference something in a bibliography.
5. Use `$`...`$` (or `\(`...`\)`) for inline math (already discussed above).

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
U_{ij}= 4\epsilon_{ij}[
                (\frac{
                    \sigma_{ij}
                     }{
                       (r_{ij})^{12} -
                    \frac{
                    \sigma_{ij} 
                    }{(r_{ij})^6
                      }
                      }]
\end{align}   
\end{document}
```

- three groups were not closed properly in the equation.
- Read about amsmath package.
- I suggest you try to write as clean as possible.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFPI.png)

Comment: I have realised that. The problem has been fixed. Thanks.